# Finding $n$ many different primes efficiently

Tags: ds.algorithms

I want to find $n$ many different primes on RAM. I can find $O(\frac{n}{\log n})$ many primes in the interval $1$ to $n$ in $O(n)$ running time. A brute force way is to find $O(\frac{n}{\log n})$ many primes in the interval $1$ to $n$ and then next in $n+1$ to $2n$ and so on. If we find primes like in this way then overall running time will be $O(n \log n)$.

**Question :** Is there any way to find $n$ many different primes in better than $O(n\log n)$ running time?

Comment: This is a great question!!  I asked a slightly related question a while back for finding relatively prime numbers: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/41005/how-hard-is-it-to-generate-a-set-of-relatively-prime-numbers-between-two-given-b

Comment: You can save a $\log\log n$ factor by using the sieve of Atkin.